# git rebase the 2nd and 3rd commit

Tags: git

Say that my very top and newest commit is A and the next after that is B and the next after that is C. How can I do git rebase if I want to combine commit B and C?

Comment: Try `git rebase --interactive HEAD^^^`, should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Removed the Github tag. If this question is specifically related to Github, please update the question with an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is with an interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will bring up your last three commits with `pick` in front of each. If you change the second instance of `pick` to `squash` and then save the file and exit, this will squash the two commits together.